# Migrate users account from Joomla 3 to another Joomla 3 manually

Tags: user, database, migration

I'm trying to migrate Joomla 3 user's information to another Joomla 3 installation.

From PHPMyAdmin I exported **_users** table and **_user_usergroup_map** to the new Database. The users appear in the user administrator sections, but when trying to log in using my credentials it say that the password is incorrect. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

The password hash are the same, but there are different installations of Joomla, I don't know if there supposed to be different hash even if the string of the password is the same...

Comment: Have you also copied the `#__usergroups` table? Are both the Joomla installations the same version?

Comment: Yes, but problem still persist.

Comment: An are you only using Joomla for user management? Or possibly a 3rd party extension such as Community Builder?

Comment: I'm only using hikashop extension

Comment: Hikashop also having one user table, you might forgot that

Answer (score 4):

Rather than migrating the users manually you could try some of the extensions available at Joomla Extensions Directory. [This page](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/migration-a-conversion/users-import-a-export) contains several extensions, both free and commercial, you'd have to look through the list and see if any of them works for you.

My recommendation is that you try [J2XML](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/j2xml) (free). I have used it before to export almost everything from Joomla (users, articles, images etc), but I think you can choose what parts of your website you want to export.

Comment: Just used J2XML last night, worked beautifully.

Comment: Another vote for J2XML. When looking for a User transfer extension it's probably best to look at the whole [Migration & Conversion](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/migration-a-conversion) category otherwise you'll miss extensions like [SP Transfer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/sp-transfer) which can also transfer users between sites.

Answer (score 1):

J2XML is an easy to use import/export solution for your Joomla!® 3 powered website.
Features:
- It allows you to export articles and users to an xml file.
- Import articles and users from an xml file (generated by J2XML)
- Send articles and user to another Joomla! site.
- CLI (command line interface)
- Export/import weblinks
- Export/import viewing access
- Export/import tags
- Export/import contacts
- 3rd party plugins support